# Как считывать числа из файла в массив?

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Имеется файла вида:

[image: пример]

Первые три строки с цифрами заключают в переменные, последующие строки требуется заключить в массивы *numpy* (два массива, начиная с четвертой строки, для первого и второго столбца соответственно).

Comment: И в чем же проблема заключается?

Comment: вопрос в том, как это реализовать, @ВладимирМартьянов . Спасибо за ответ

Comment: Что именно как реализовать? Открытие файла, чтение, numpy? Вы язык-то вообще знаете?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов добавление в массив numpy указанных строк и столбцов

Comment: То есть, у вас из файла данные уже прочитаны и помещены в некие "строки" и "столбцы"? Как эти структуры у вас реализованы? Меняйте соответствующим образом вопрос...

Comment: а что делать с `comments`? Там фиксированное число строк?

Comment: @MaxU это одна строка, нашел такое решение array = np.loadtxt('fileName', skiprows=4, delimiter=' ', usecols=(1))

Comment: @AlexeyPiskunov, т.е. numpy массивы всегда начинаются с пятой строки?

Comment: @MaxU Да, 5 строка и все что ниже

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

file = """10
2
3
100 100
250 50
100 250
100 100
250 50
100 250
100 100
250 50
100 250
100 100
250 50
100 250
100 100
250 50
100 250"""

file_data = file.split('\n')
# массив из первых 3 значений
first_values = np.array(file_data[0:3])

data = np.array([couple.split() for couple in file_data[3:]])
```

В переменной `first_values` первые три значения, в переменной `data` ваши данные в виде матрицы (строки столбцы)

Answer (score 1):

Пример:

Исходные данные прочитанные в одну переменную - `data`:

```
In [80]: print(data)
comments
10
2
3
100 100
250 50
100 250
100 100
250 50
100 250
```

Решение:

```
In [81]: from io import StringIO
```

читаем строки начиная с 5-й в 2D матрицу:

```
In [82]: a = np.loadtxt(StringIO('\n'.join(data.split('\n')[4:])))

In [83]: a
Out[83]:
array([[ 100.,  100.],
       [ 250.,   50.],
       [ 100.,  250.],
       [ 100.,  100.],
       [ 250.,   50.],
       [ 100.,  250.]])
```

Разделяем по столбцам:

```
In [87]: a1 = a.ravel()[::2]

In [88]: a2 = a.ravel()[1::2]

In [89]: a1
Out[89]: array([ 100.,  250.,  100.,  100.,  250.,  100.])

In [90]: a2
Out[90]: array([ 100.,   50.,  250.,  100.,   50.,  250.])
```

---

Еще удобнее будет воспользоваться модулем Pandas:

```
In [102]: fn = r'C:\Temp\.data\727039.dat'

In [103]: import pandas as pd

In [104]: df = pd.read_csv(fn, delim_whitespace=True, skiprows=4, names=['col1','col2'])

In [105]: df
Out[105]:
   col1  col2
0   100   100
1   250    50
2   100   250
3   100   100
4   250    50
5   100   250

In [106]: a1, a2 = df['col1'].values, df['col2'].values

In [107]: a1
Out[107]: array([100, 250, 100, 100, 250, 100], dtype=int64)

In [108]: a2
Out[108]: array([100,  50, 250, 100,  50, 250], dtype=int64)
```